# Microsoft Excel Date calculations

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My team has turnaround deadlines depending on specific stages of a process. For example:
if a request is received they have 21 days to complete the request. 
if a request is received and further information is needed from the client, my team needs to send a request for further information within 21 days and then check to see if the information has been returned within a further 28 day window.

I want to track:
Date request received
Date further information has been requested
Date request should be finalised, based on whether the request could be managed with what information we had OR in the event further information is needed, the revised date the team needs to follow up and close the case.

My sticking point is getting a due date calculation to generate that takes into consideration whether there is further information requested or not.

There are variable timelines depending on the nature of the clients case and this is creating difficulty for me to track the different possible deadlines.

The main variables are: 
From the date a request is received, we have 21 days to provide a response. 
If a request is received, and further information is needed, we have 21 days from the date of the request received to ask for further information. The client has 28 days to return this to us.

Once the further information is returned to us, we have 14 days to complete the request or ask for further information again. IN the case there is no further information needed, the due date will be 14 days from when the information is received. If further information is needed again, we need to ask for it within the 14 days and the client has a further 28 days to return it to us.

When the client returns the second request for information to us, we will have a further 14 days from the receipt of the second lot of information to provide an outcome.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Conditional requirements aren't super difficult in Excel, but how to apply them in this case depends on the number of records and where you want this information drawn from and output to. Perhaps a simple formula would work for a few records, but for many records on an ongoing basis a macro may work best. Also, is this just for reporting? Can an argument be made that Excel is not the best place to do this? Would you be better served placing this information in a database and extracting it from there?

Comment: Is "my sticking point" the actual problem you're looking for help with?  If so, why not just assign "further information request" as a true/false value and then test for it in your formula?

Answer (score 0):

You have listed three different timeframes.
The request received date can occur only once, but the further information required and the further information received can occur multiple times.

I am going to assume that you have a worksheet for a particular job and that the relevant deadline is the latest deadline (ie if your requested information on day 1 of 21, and the further info was received on day 2 of 21, the deadline would stay at the remaining 19 days, rather than decreasing to the 14 days).

Layout:

- Reserve column A for the dates that Requests for Further Information have been sent out.
- Reserve column B for the dates that the additional information has been received
- A descriptions in column C of action at that date etc
- General details section, keeping numbers clear of columns A and B, say with the Original Request Date in cell C8.

Get three cells to keep track of the various  possible deadlines with the following formulas and then one last one to select the maximum date of these as your final deadline.

> Request deadline =C8+21
>   Client to supply info deadline =MAX(A:A)+28
>   Process additional info =MAX(B:B)+14

As the job progresses,  the customer service rep can add an extra line into the spreadsheet, with the date in column A or B depending on whether the information is being requested or received, and the final due date will automatically update.